# Ajax GET is never successful, but POST is (same code)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I don't understand why my code below works fine when method is set to 'POST' but not when it is 'GET'. The backend code executes perfectly in both cases but in the front end I end up in the error: handler when method is 'GET', and only 'POST' gets me into the success: handler.

My return object from the backend has AllowGet set, and I'm not sending any params to the method. Why am I getting 500 internal server error?

```
// Front end
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '@Url.Action("GetBusinessList")',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // do some stuff
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, text) { 
        console.log(xhr.status); // 500
        console.log(xhr.text); // undefined
        console.log(xhr.responseText); // my error page's html
    }
});
```

```
// The backend code
public JsonResult GetBusinessList()
{
    //...

    JsonResult returnObj = new JsonResult
    {
        Data = new
        {
            MyList = businessList // this is a List<MyType>
        },
        ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };

    return Json(returnObj);
```

Just to reiterate: The backend code is being executed successfully when method is set to 'POST' and 'GET'. The jquery code is possibly at fault, but I do not know why.

Having [HttpGet] on the action does nothing - in fact I have my own attribute on there to check HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest . Taking this off and replacing with HttpGet has no effect.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code on the server to find out what the actual error is?

Comment: Why is the action name different? `GetBusinessList` v's `GetBusinessSources`?

Comment: Debug in VS (I assume you're using this IDE?).  Go to debug > exceptions > Common Language Runtime Exceptions check 'thrown'  Perform your request again and check the exception that should now be thrown and execution stopped on.  I'm wondering if this is a problem with routing and you're hitting the 'multiple actions found for request' exception.

Comment: Sorry the differing method names were a typo when putting it onto StackOverflow. That is not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the asp.net mvc does not allow an HTTP GET request with a JSON payload. You need to explicitly allow the behavior by using **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet** as the second parameter to the **Json** method like following.

```
return Json(returnObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: @VictorySaber - you should try this one.. because JsonRequestBehavior is "DenyGet" by default.. so specifying it explicitly to "AllowGet" should make your Get action returning properly.

Comment: So even though returnObj has JsonRequestBehavior set to AllowGet, I need to set it in the new Json I am creating..... ah, let me try it.

Comment: Of course. I am returning a Json object which by default has DenyGet set. The object _inside_ the Json doesn't matter. I knew it would be something silly. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply return the returnObj instead of Json(returnObj). That already contains required behavior.

Comment: This way of returning the JSON works fine elsewhere in my site, where I am doing POST. I'll try this to see if it makes the GET work - can you explain why?

Comment: Yes you were right, I've explained why in Azim's post.

Comment: @VictorySaber - try, this should work also because Json method itself returns a JsonResult, so if you already have that created, just returning it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the HTTP Get attribute to your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetBusinessList()
{
    ....
}
```

If you open the developer tools window, the error message should be shown in the console window.

You also need to check the URL you are calling, which is different to your controller method, in your question description.

Comment: URL is fine, my mistake in putting on SO. HttpGet makes no difference. The backend executes fine with POST and GET.